# How to get difference in seconds between two strings?

Tags: python, time, python-datetime

I have two strings in Python that are used to store user entered times. They are formatted as hh:mm:ss - eg 09:17:34

What is the easiest way to find the difference, in seconds, between these two times? The times will always be on the same day, so no need to worry about overlapping midnight, etc.

If I use string slicing to take out the relevant digits, then use `datetime.datetime()`, I can set up a `datetime` object for each, but I need to give it a date as well as the time I have.

I've played around with the `time` module, but this doesn't seem to have an easy way of working out differences in the way that using `.total_seconds` on a `timedelta` object does.

Is there any easier way?

Comment: Why not convert them to a meaningful representation - like numbers or even dates?

Comment: looks like a job for `strptime`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) *directly* on the two time strings; a default date (1900-01-01) is used when you are parsing just time components.

```
time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestring1, '%H:%M:%S')
time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestring2, '%H:%M:%S')
difference = time2 - time1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `strptime`:

```
from datetime import datetime
t1 = datetime.strptime("02:03:04", "%H:%M:%S")
t2 = datetime.strptime("05:08:06", "%H:%M:%S")
t2 - t1
# datetime.timedelta(0, 11102)
(t2 - t1).seconds
# 11102
```